# Where is the employer save button?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, employer

I did a candidate search (in FF 3.5 & Chrome) and found two candidates I was interested in contacting. However, when I tried to click on their names, nothing happened (even though they were links) and when I looked for a "save" button near their names, I couldn't find one (even though it said at the bottom of the page there should be one).

This image illustrates my confusion:

[alt text http://rookery5.aviary.com/storagev12/2592000/2592095_1943_625x625.jpg](http://rookery5.aviary.com/storagev12/2592000/2592095_1943_625x625.jpg)

How do I contact these candidates?

Comment: Are you playing missle command?

Comment: ROFL. Yes, that is exactly what is happening. This is a secret feature of the employer side of careers.

This is actually meant to illustrate where I'm expecting the save button to be. I see the illustration of what the save button is supposed to look like at the bottom, and then the arrows show where I'm looking expecting the actual save buttons to appear and they aren't.

Comment: Neither of those two users are me so I'm not going to help you!

Comment: There is no way to visit their profile. When you click their name nothing happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been fixed - proceed!

Comment: How am I supposed to believe you when you don't post a screenshot with big red arrows pointing to the fix?