# Missing Candidates Found box when doing a location search in "free trial mode"

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs, internet-explorer-6

Using the screen shot from [Where Is The Employer Save Button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31581/where-is-the-employer-save-button), there is clearly a CV that exists with `Bloomington, Indiana United States` as the location.  However, when I do a Trial Search the Number of Candidates Found disappears.  Is this a feature that is unavailable to the Trial Mode account? or is this a bug?

[image: Careers image with missing Candidates Found box]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this in a browser other than IE?

I'm not aware of any IE7 or IE8 problems -- and we fully test on those browsers.*

<sub>* but I can never really trust any version of IE any more.. even IE8 has burned us with that massive `<pre>` bug.</sub>

Comment: Tried it in FF3.5 and it worked no problem - IE6 not so much.

Comment: IE6 is not a tier 1, A-level support browser for us. We expect things to be flaky in it. So that's by-design

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this as an unregistered user in IE8 with and without IE7 compatibility mode.

Can you give me more details?  If you refresh the page does it ever come back?  What are the specific steps you take to reproduce this issue?